# Jenkins file Script

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, devops, code-snippets, jenkins-groovy

Can any one please tell me that we can generate entire Jenkins file script with snippet generator?
I have to write Jenkins file including steps like Check Out Code, Build using Gradle, Pushing to nexus, Generate Sonar Report and Generate Package for deployment.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate all the parts with the snippet generator but you have to put it all together in your defined stages.

Maybe you can start from [examples](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-examples/tree/master/jenkinsfile-examples) or search in github for [jenkinsfile](https://github.com/search?q=filename%3AJenkinsfile%20language%3AGroovy%20language%3AGroovy&type=Code&ref=advsearch&l=Groovy&l=Groovy)
But be aware of the two different flavours of the Jenkinsfile:

- scripted
- declarative